# How to fetch value from datagrid to another form in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

I have a Datagrid on one page, when user clicks on cell of datagrid, it should open another form with labels and textboxes and it should fill it with relevant data fetching from the SQL Database.

I have searched and found out

```
response.querystring["string"]
```

But due to its visibility cant use it.

I am pretty new with coding in asp, done some on WINFORM using C#, so I was trying to do through creating an object but it didn't work, so what is the correct way of doing it?

Thanks

Comment: you can store value in session or cookie and used them on another page.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt' work with data grid but if it's anythign like gridview then you have an option to use template fields and customize the links for these.

Here is an example template field from grid view that can be customized to suite your needs

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer Status" SortExpression="IsCustomer">
       <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
       <ItemTemplate>
            <a href='yournewpage.aspx?param=<%# Eval("Column_name")) %>' alt="" />
       </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: this will show the param's value will be visible on the url, this will not be secured as it might contain some important info